# How to convert data set to JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am facing error in java script serializer

My error

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.

MY Code in mvc controller

```
 public string LoadALLa()
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string strRet = "";
        IHometelPMSUow uow = new HometelPMSUow();

        Proc procedure = new Proc(strConString);
        DataSet getdetails = procedure.getpropertydetails(3);
        if (getdetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            strRet = jss.Serialize(getdetails);
        else
            strRet = "No Items";
        return strRet;
    }
```

Comment: this link might help... http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/c-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-c.html .... If you still want to convert dataset to json, then here is the way you can do that... http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 0):

It look's like you want to return a JSON, is it right ?

If yes, trying using the code below on your action method on your controller class:

```
 return Json(dataSet, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

if it still doesn work, try parsing the datatable instead a dataset:

```
 return Json(dataSet.Tables[0], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```